# Delete columns in Google Sheet with python in a test with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-sheets

I'm trying to clear some columns in Google Sheets using gspread so what better fit was an insert_cols () function, but it returned with an error. I tried to use update () but it didn't work either.

```
sheet.delete_columns(1,15)
    
sheet.insert_cols(1,15)
```

And return

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter for insert_cols takes a list. You are passing an int, so when the function tries to call len on the int, you get a TypeError.

Try changing to `sheet.insert_cols([1, 15])`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you command is correct or not?

Click [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumn(Integer))!

Sheet API for deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// Columns start at "1" - this deletes the first two columns
sheet.deleteColumns(1, 2);
```